# Calculator app does not open in Appium Inspector in Mac when launched iOS Simulator from it

Tags: ios, macos, applescript, appium, automator

I have been trying to launch Calculator app in Appium Inspector in my Mac Catalina using iOS Simulator but to no avail. I need to identify Calculator's actions/events to do some data driven testing.  I was able to do so for Calendar using bundle ID com.apple.iCal but not so for Calculator with bundle ID com.apple.calculator. I am using below code:
{
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "automationName": "XCUITest",
  "noReset": false,
  "deviceName": "iPhone 11 Pro",
  "platformVersion": "13.3",
  "App Category": "Utilities",
  "Bundle name": "Calculator",
  "bundleId": "com.apple.calculator",
}
 I get below error in Inspector though Simulator loads(err attached[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qPOf.png)):

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: App with bundle identifier 'com.apple.calculator' unknown
I have tried putting "/Applications/Calculator.app" value in "app" key but it results in:

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Bad app: /Applications/Calculator.app. App paths need to be absolute or an URL to a compressed app file: The application at '/Applications/Calculator.app' does not exist or is not accessible

Could somebody please look into this issue?

I have MacBook Pro Mac OS Catalina

Many Thanks!

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Calculator app is unavailable on iOS Simulator.

If you experiment with testing, try a different app like Settings or Shortcuts (you can create shortcuts to calculate things).

If you need to test the Calculator app, switch to testing with real devices.

Good luck!

Comment: I am able to identify elements using Simulator now for applications other than Calculator. Thanks!